# Detecting several instances of a word on one line C#

Tags: c#, text, console-application

In a file management program I've built I have a method to find words. You input a word you want the program to find. Like `True` or `False`. You also give it a filepath through typing it into the program.

```
public void searchForWord()
        {
            using (StreamReader fs = File.OpenText(filePath))
            {

                int count = 0; //counts the number of times wordResponse is found.
                int lineNumber = 0;
                while (!fs.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = fs.ReadLine();
                    lineNumber++;
                    int position = line.IndexOf(wordSearch);
                    if (position != -1)
                    {
                        count++;
                        Console.WriteLine("Match#{0} line {1}: {2}", count, lineNumber, wordSearch);
                    }
                }
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("your word was not found!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your word " + "'" + wordSearch + "'" + " was found " + count + " times!");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
```

The program is functional, but has one bug, even though it functions. This is a snippet from the testfile I've been running it on.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis lectus sem, eleifend in enim vel, imperdiet pretium justo. 
Vivamus sit amet arcu sed metus rutrum varius vitae vitae turpis. Quisque aliquet mauris lacus, quis aliquam metus placerat vel. 
Proin eleifend tortor velit, False quis aliquam arcu congue ut. Fusce sed mattis purus, sed vehicula diam. False Nullam in leo sit amet massa pharetra semper et vel diam. 
Sed at dolor aliquam libero bibendum porta.
```

If you read through the third line of the paragraph I've been testing on, it has two sets of `False` but my program only detects the first one.

As shown here:

```
Match#1 line 3: False
Match#2 line 7: False
Match#3 line 17: False
Match#4 line 19: False
Match#5 line 24: False
Your word 'False' was found 5 times!
```

This is the output my program gives me. How do I adjust it so that it takes into account two or more instances of a word on one line?

Comment: IndexOf has an extra overload that takes a start position. Use that in a loop where the start position is the last value you got from indexOf until IndexOf returns -1

Comment: Instead of just finding if the word is found in the string, you're interested in finding _all_ occurences in the string, or rather, the count of the occurences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found using indexOf was the following.

```
public void searchForWord()
        {
            using (StreamReader fs = File.OpenText(filePath))
            {

                int count = 0; //counts the number of times wordResponse is found.
                int lineNumber = 0;
                while (!fs.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = fs.ReadLine();
                    lineNumber++;
                    int position = line.IndexOf(wordSearch);
                    int i = 0;
                    while ((i = line.IndexOf(wordSearch, i)) != -1)
                    {
                        i++;
                        if (position != -1)
                        {
                            count++;
                            Console.WriteLine("Match#{0} line {1}: {2}", count, lineNumber, wordSearch);
                        }
                    }

                }
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("your word was not found!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your word " + "'" + wordSearch + "'" + " was found " + count + " times!");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
```